# Connection close header removed by haproxy

Tags: haproxy

My setup is based on 2 apache nodes behind haproxy.

In one PHP script we have to send the header "Connection: close" but if I analyse the response headers in Firebug, this header is not present.

In a setup without haproxy the header is present, so I guess haproxy is removing this header because of some configuration issue.

Which are the options in haproxy which I should look at?

Comment: Is this related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40763485/1695906)?  HAProxy *should* remove this header, since [`option http-keep-alive`](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#option%20http-keep-alive) is the default.  It closes the backend connection as appropriate, while removing the header in order to allow the browser to stay connected for faster subsequent requests.

Comment: yes it is related. The solution there works but I also wanted to understand what's the reason. So if http-keep-alive is the default then it makes sense that the header is removed. But is there an option that tells haproxy just to pass thru the header if it is activley set?